# How can I use a Gulp task to install a Bower package?

Tags: gulp, bower, gulp-bower

I'm trying to use gulp tasks to install Bower packages as and when needed. Is this possible? I thought something along the lines of:

```
var bower = require ('gulp-bower')

gulp.task('get-normalize', function() {
  return bower({cmd: 'install normalize-scss'})
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.bowerDir))
});
```

But this doesn't work as hoped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to pass arguments to a `bower` command is incredibly weird and it doesn't seem to be documented anywhere. Had to look at the [source](https://github.com/zont/gulp-bower/blob/4c8120f/index.js#L153-L164) to figure this out.

Command arguments need to be passed as an array of strings and that array itself must be the first element of an array:

```
gulp.task('get-normalize', function() {
  return bower({cmd:'install', directory:config.bowerDir}, [['normalize-scss']]);
});
```

You also need to use the `directory` option instead of `gulp.dest()` when using the `install` command.

Comment: That's awesome! Thank you.